# Modify a POST body element before calling POST operation($http) in angular

Tags: angularjs

I want to copy one list(investDtls) to another list (listInvestOptions) which is part of POST body.

Below is the code snippet:

```
app.controller("OneClickController", function($scope,$location, $resource, $http){
            $scope.investDtls ={};


        $scope.submitOneClick = function(investDtls) {
        //$scope.oneClick.submitOneClickDetails.listInvestOptions = angular.copy(investDtls);
        $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : '/investor/api/v1/oneclick',
            data : $scope.oneClick
        }).success(function(response) {
        $scope.oneClick.submitOneClickDetails.listInvestOptions = angular.copy(investDtls);
        //alert("success");
        }); 
        }
                    });
```

Here I have some fields inside **investDtls**  list and I want to copy the contents into another list(**listInvestOptions**) which is part of a POST body 
and I am accessing it like:

**$scope.oneClick.submitOneClickDetails.listInvestOptions**

But as per the above code snippet, list is getting copied after the POST operation.

I want to perform the copy operation just before calling the POST block

```
$scope.oneClick.submitOneClickDetails.listInvestOptions = angular.copy(investDtls);

$http({
                    method : 'POST',
                    url : '/investor/api/v1/oneclick',
                    data : $scope.oneClick
                })
```

If I am proceeding as above, it will not work as **$scope.oneClick.submitOneClickDetails.listInvestOptions**  part is not accessible unless POST block is exexuted.

Hope I am clear from my side.. Any more clarifications most welcome..  :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/26IaQKTz2QVKB8MkKEzT?p=preview) and let me know it if helps in any way.

JS

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("OneClickController", function($scope, $location, $http){
    $scope.investDtls = {'test': 'blah'};
    $scope.oneClick = {submitOneClickDetails: {listInvestOptions: null}};

    $scope.submitOneClick = function(investDtls) {
        $scope.oneClick.submitOneClickDetails.listInvestOptions = angular.copy(investDtls);
        $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : 'data.json',
            data : $scope.oneClick
        }).success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            console.log($scope.oneClick);
        }); 
    }
});
```

Markup

```
<body ng-controller="OneClickController">
    <button ng-click="submitOneClick(investDtls)">Submit</button>
</body>
```

Note that I am using GET for test purposes.

Comment: Hi,

I am initializing the POST body list as below:

$scope.oneClick.submitOneClickDetails = {};

Now I can copy the list. 

But after the line($scope.oneClick.submitOneClickDetails.listInvestOptions = angular.copy(investDtls)) where we are copying the list
the controller is not getting called  but only the success() method is getting executed at the end.